# iOS Cordova PushPlugin

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications

I want to add **Push Notification** in my **iOS Cordova Application**. I have tried `cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git` this plugin . But it looks like it is for the PhoneGap application.And also it is not building

**See the error Image**
[image]

Help me to implement PushNotification in Cordova

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you the great [OneSignal](http://onesignal.com/) online service. We currently use it in all our Cordova apps flawlessy

Comment: I have already used this plugin in my previous proj and created all required api's. so i cant change any new service. <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin" />

Comment: Could you please tell to use this plugin for cordova?

Answer (score 0):

You use deprecated plugin. Please use plugin from link: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push.

It works on Cordova, on Android and iOS, even on Windows Phone.

Comment: Thank You.There seems to be No documentation. Could you send any tutorial / Documentation Please.

Comment: Of course there is documentation in the readme theres links to API, examples.